# ASP.NET Core random ampersand in url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My application is an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API.

Lets say I have the following controller:

```
  [Produces("application/json")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetUrl()
  {
         return this.StatusCode(200, JsonConvert.SerializeObject("www.example.com/?foo=1&bar=2"));
  }
```

Sometimes the controller returns the following URL:

```
www.example.com/?foo=1&bar=2
```

And sometimes it returns:

```
www.example.com/?foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

Is there a reason why it only sometimes converts the `&` to an `&amp;`?

Thank you

Comment: Define **sometimes**? With the same code above? Once with and once without? Hard to believe tbh.

Comment: lets say in 0.5% it changes the & to an &amp;

Comment: I know its pretty weird it might work if I just return this string:
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(url);
Just wanted to know if anyone has an idea why this happens

Comment: If the code above really produce this behavior, it sounds like a bug and you'd  be more appropiate to open an issue here https://github.com/aspnet/mvc/issues

Comment: Would probably be the best idea..
alteas Im not the only one who has no clue whats going on in there

Comment: It's really unlikely - something must be changing between these calls - track what that might be. If you call the method from a unit test 100 times, with the same exact parameters, are you getting different results? If not, the method is working consistently, and it's much more likely the data (incoming parameters) or the environment (calling client, protocol, etc) is the issue.

Comment: I actually tested it with unit tests and yes the results are different